# Confusion regarding the location of myelinated and unmyelinated nerve fibres

Tags: neuroscience, central-nervous-system, peripheral-nervous-system, neuron, autonomic-nervous-system

So, what I understand by neural system terms is

1. **Central nervous system [CNS]**- consist of brain and spinal cord
2. **Peripheral nervous system [PNS]** - consist of cranial and spinal nerves *(all the nerves in the body)*
3. A further classification of PNS is

   I) Autonomous nervous system
   II)somatic nervous system

*(Here, my understanding is that both the system [**somatic and Autonomous nervous  system**] are made up of cranial and spinal nerve, and they are just classified based on the different organs that they are functioning upon **[i.e for somatic it is skeleton muscles and for autonomous, it is heart, smooth muscles and involuntary organs]** and not on composition ,since both systems consist of cranial and spinal nerves)*

Now,i read the lines that are there (beside the red line) in picture below and I am highly confused now.

[image: where can we find myelinated and unmyelinated nerve fibres]

Now, it says that myelinated nerve fibers are found in cranial and spinal nerves i.e all the nerves in the body a.k.a Peripheral nervous system.

And on another note, it says unmyelinated nerve fibres are found in autonomous nervous system and somatic nervous system.

but isn't autonomous and somatic  nervous system makes up the peripheral nervous system?

so according to the first point (myelinated nerve fibres is present in peripheral nervous system.)

Therefore, It( **somatic and autonomous nervous system** i.e the peripheral system) should contain myelinated nerve fibres but here ,in just the next line ,it states that it contains unmyelinated nerve fibre?

By my understanding of the above mentioned terms......
My confusion here is.......

Does it contain both (myelinated and unmyelinated nerve fibre)?

or is there a printing mistake?

or is my understanding of terminology is wrong?
If so, please correct me.

Thank you so much

Comment: Where is this text from? Does it happen to be an Indian textbook? It's been a long time since I've seen one of these Indian textbook translation questions but I suspect this may be one...

Comment: @BryanKrause       Yes. This (confusing and unclear)text is from  "NCERT Biology" 11th std Indian Textbook. I will be highly grateful if you can clear this or anyone. Thank you so much

Comment: I don't know where these textbooks come from, but they aren't written by anyone who knows what they are talking about. I don't know why many Indian textbooks work this way. I'd highly recommend getting a different book or just learning from Wikipedia.